# Wrote an application for a friend. Who is the owner of the software?

Tags: freelancing, product-owner

Friend asked me to develop a software application for him. I did and he paid me.
There was no written contract. I live in UK and he resides in Canada.

My question is: who is the owner of the software now?
Can my friend make and sell copies without my permission? Can I do the same?

I'm asking this because another person also wants to buy it, but friend insists on receiving some kind of sale commission, because the software was originally written at his request.

Comment: It is 110% his. Next time do a contract.

Comment: It can't be 110% his. It's 100% at most.

Comment: Yeah, in the United States we call this a "work for hire."  Generally speaking, the person paying you to write software for them has complete rights to do whatever they wish with it.

Comment: In all my freelance work it clearly states in my contract that the code belongs to the client.  I can't see how they would want it any other way.

Comment: @marco-fiset: A fact of which Mathew was probably acutely aware when he wrote 110% to further hammer his point.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I got the point, I was just trying to be funny hehe.

Comment: Did he pay you a peanut or a significant amount? Legally it may not matter. But morally the amount he paid would affect his claim of ownership.

Comment: It's always best to do a contract. Even with friends. You never know, they may come back later and claim your big social network application was their idea!

Comment: If you wrote it once, then you can write it again with a separate code base.  It'll give you a nice clean break.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I don't think it's that simple.  There's stuff about a shop right but they don't by default get copyright, I think.  It's complicated enough that they probably either want a lawyer or to just come to a clearer agreement, maybe both.

Comment: @BillLeeper - I hope that your contracts also state clearly that "intellectual property transfers on satisfaction of contract"; otherwise you can get *royally* shafted by your client, who would legally own whatever code you had written if they had ever paid you *anything* in return for it, whether you'd been paid in full or not. The above statement, one sentence, states unequivocally that it's *yours* until you agree it's theirs.

Comment: You need a lawyer honestly. Absolutely no one here is qualified to answer this, so either come to an agreement with your friend or get a lawyer to tell both of you who has what rights in truth. Or get a lawyer and have the lawyer argue you have all rights if you want to be a dick about it.

Comment: Without a licensing agreement in place, there is a case to be made that your friend has a *non-exclusive* license to do with your work as you wish, meaning that he cannot exclude you from also using any of it in your future work or selling it to others. For example, what if you re-used some library functions that you wrote for another project? Does your friend own part of that project?  The verbal agreement between you and your friend is satisfied because he got the deliverables.  Let's put it this way: do you own Windows because you bought a Windows PC? :)

Comment: @JimmyHoffa Where would you recommend this question (and similar legal inquiries) be posted for future reference?

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA your lawyer's voicemail

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA - I've updated my answer to reflect a subtlety that wasn't quite obvious before.  _This_ question would have to be determined by an attorney who could say if this was work-for-hire or if it was commissioned.  The difference is huge in this case.  For any future work, insist upon a written agreement between both parties specifying who owns the copyright.  And if you're in the same boat as Michal, then contact an attorney.

Comment: @GlenH7 Fortunately, no. The work I do for friends I have no desire to own, or I would do a contract or some sort of written agreement. I was more hoping for possibly a law exchange or some similar resource just in case I ever needed it in the future (contingencies and the like). Thank you for the extra clarification, though, I appreciate it.

Comment: @KeithS yes my contract had me fairly well covered.  I also stipulated that I controlled access to the source code during development and would't turn control over to the client until final payment.  Additionally based on a bad experience where a friend didn't pay, I also asked for 1/3 up front.  I have a good client, so all has been well, but even in the best of cases you need to protect yourself legally.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Without a contract in place, most common law says that the program and copyright to the code belong to your friend.  Essentially, he employed you for a task and paid for your labor so you were his employee*.

And that implies that you aren't allowed to sell a copy to a second friend since *you* don't own that application.  Your first friend owns it.

However, it also depends upon the verbal (IM'd, or email'd) terms that you guys agreed to when specifying the project.  Verbal contracts are a pain to sort out because it's a you-said vs. he-said argument.  But if your first friend agrees that you also still "own" the software then you could sell it to your second friend.

In my opinion, the right thing to do would be to give your first friend a cut of the sale.  Ideally, he's not asking for all of the sale, but he could be entitled to make the claim.  You should also discuss what limits there will be for any additional sales that might occur.  Hopefully, you'll come to an amicable agreement.

Legally, there's probably not much that can occur.  You're in completely separate jurisdictions, and I'm willing to be that the sums involved are not enough to justify an international lawsuit.  Worst case is that you'll have lost a friend, and perhaps with some hard feelings.

Talk it over with your first friend and find an amicable agreement.  He does have a basis for his claims.

---

**Update:**
There is a *huge* distinction to be made between an application that was created under terms of employment and an application that was commissioned.

If the work was created under terms of employment, an implied contract in this case, then the copyright would belong with your first friend who paid you to write the program.  US law recognizes the term "work-for-hire" as an employment term.  Canadian law regrettably acknowledges the US term due to the number of Canadian | US contracts, but it's not a preferred term within Canadian contract law.

On the other hand, if the work was created under terms of a commission then full copyright remains with you, the creator of the work.

And there's one more slightly crazy exception to all that.  If your friend was requesting the work on behalf of the [Canadian Crown](http://canadiancrown.gc.ca/eng/1332788662861/1332788724918) then all copyright would belong to the Crown.

The nuances between creation under employment versus creation from a commission are ones that an attorney would have to settle for you.  That sort of determination is well outside the scope of what Programmers can offer.

Also off-topic, but slightly interesting, is that photographs and illustrations have a whole gamut of exceptions to the copyright provisions of commissioned work.

---

For some not-so-casual reading, here are some additional references.

- The link to the [UK's IPO on this subject](http://www.ipo.gov.uk/types/copy/c-ownership/c-commissioned.htm)
  <sub>Hat tip to Bart van Ingen Schenau for the reference</sub>
- A UK & Ireland specific article regarding [Copyright for custom code](http://jiplp.oxfordjournals.org/content/2/7/473.full.pdf?keytype=ref&ijkey=PUyOS40LmBKlBXU)
- An article from the NZ Ministry of Economic Development [discussing the effects of copyright and commissioned work](http://www.nzipp.org.nz/NzippWeb/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=6pHDd5XX90s%3D&tabid=153)
- A site from the U of Saskatchewan [confirming copyright belonging to first author for commissioned works](http://www.usask.ca/copyright/basics/basic-info/index.php)
- A link to the CA Association of Professional Image Creators discussing some of the nuances of [commissioned photographs and illustrations](http://www.capic.org/resources.html?screen=bp&t=bp_section&chapter=What+You+Sell)

Comment: Actually, due to the absence of a contract, the copyright lies with @Michal. See http://www.ipo.gov.uk/types/copy/c-ownership/c-commissioned.htm.

Comment: @GlenH7 - thanks for the reply. I agree with you and I'm willing to give him a cut. I was bit surprised when others pointed out that under US law he'd be an owner of both code and the program itself.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau - does UK jurisdiction apply in this case or Canadian one?

Comment: @Michal: As fas as I could determine, the UK law applies as you are a UK citizen. In any case, I did not see a significant difference between UK and Canadian law here.

Comment: Someone please create an updated answer that is correct!

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau - I made some additions to the answer that I think you'll agree with.  The decision point would hing on whether it was commissioned work or work-for-hire.  Thanks again for bringing up the references to commissioned work belonging to the first creator.

Comment: @Michal - looks like jurisdiction wouldn't matter;  I found references that indicates CA law is pretty closely aligned with UK & Ireland law for this area.  The second link regarding copyright for custom code may be of interest to you.  I skimmed some of it, but did not read all the way through.

Comment: @GlenH7 thank you for the answer and additional reading material.